# How do you use PDO to see what was inserted into a database (PHP)?

Tags: php, pdo

Using PDO, I would like to obtain the columns and data that were entered for a SQL insertion statement. Is there a way I can do this? I know that fetchAll() can be used for querying statements like SELECT.

```
 $db = new PDO("sqlite:app.db");
 $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
 $insertion = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, password_hash) values(:name, :password_hash)");
 $insertion->execute(array("name" => $this->name, "password_hash" => $this->password_hash));
```

Ultimately, I would like to see/return the row that was entered into the database without querying for the name + password_hash combination.

Thanks!

**EDIT/Clarification:**

I now understand that I can easily retrieve the last ID, but my question was specifically in regards to whether it's somehow possible to return all the inserted data without querying.

Comment: you just inserted the data, so by definition you already had the data in PHP. you cannot retrieve data from an insert - you'd have to do a select. and for that, unless you have some weird field-type mismatch or outright query failure, would just return what you already have available.

Comment: I thought perhaps there was some function on `$insertion` that would return the "results" of the `execute` function. Really, I'm trying to get the ID (primary key) for the insertion. I thought about using `lastInsertId()`, but I wonder if that would present a problem if multiple users simultaneously inserted data.

Comment: no, lastinsertid only returns the ID of the record YOU inserted. it'd be utterly useless if it provided the id of some other user's insert. it'd be impossible to reliably insert related records (e.g. parent/child) otherwise.

Comment: Okay, I see, I thought maybe it would check against the last inserted from the database. Thanks.

Comment: no, it's not `select max(id)`. again that'd be useless, and return the last id inserted by ANYONE. internally mysql will generate the id, and save it into a connection-specific variable. that's all last_insert_id() does - query that per-connection variable, so you only get YOUR id, and not anyone else's.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the data still available in the variables in your script, or fetch the freshly inserted database column.

For the latter, you can do a `SELECT` using the from the `INSERT` generated primary key. You can obtain it with [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.lastinsertid.php)